# How to display data into table view cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to display data into table view cell , how I can achive this. Please help me

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *feedsTableIdentifier = @"FeedsTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:feedsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FeedsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=tableViewCell;
        self.tableViewCell=nil;
    }
    title=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    title.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];

    postedBy=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    postedBy.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];

    onDate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    onDate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Please Help me.

Comment: what do you mean by display data?

Comment: what you want exactly.. this is your code or you have just give example to show this type of data you want to show

Comment: I want to set the values of title,postedby and ondate. These are the labels on tableviewcell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from reading this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7

Try to study how the interface builder/storyboard can help you, setting IBOutlets instead of trying access them using `[cell viewWithTag:3]`. Using IBOutlets you can just refer to them by name, like:

```
postedByLabel.text = @"Some user";
titleLabel.text = @"A title!";
```

Now for the date you better read about `NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter` :)

Answer (score 1):

I think You are new Iphone Developer .. in your code have  many error/Bug ...

I think  You want

[" How to create the customize cell"` please refer this link....for you help](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CellController *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CellController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.menuLabel.text = [self.homeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

You need to have a custom CellController setup and associated with a cell in your storyboard.  You then need to set up the three labels you want (title, postedBy, onDate) in your custom cell so you can insert the data into the labels.

This tutorial might help you out: http://ijoshsmith.com/2011/07/16/creating-a-custom-uitableviewcell-in-ios-4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"Some text";
```

If you don't want to create a custom UITableViewCell class.